I was writing a code for the skin diesease AI on python and using the tensorflow module but i keep getting the missingimports error
from keras.optimizers import Adam // it is not recognising the keras.optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint // it is not recognising the keras.callbacks
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Dense, Dropout // it is not recognising the keras.layers
I have alreadt installed tensorflow and keras and they are up to date and working fine. the error is only showing in this

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
